# Excel VBA - Force Uppercase Error when Contents Deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to force a cell to take an uppercase value, which works, using the code below.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B9", "F10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
    Target = UCase(Target)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""
```

However, when the contents of the cell is deleted (which may be required) I receive the following error "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

If you can shed any light on this, that'd be great!

Answer (score 2):

Target is a Range, not String (assuming you are using Worksheet_Change event).

The should be multiple cells changing at once, not empty cells.

When you have one single cell, all fine, because **value of** Target evaluate to Target.Value which is generaly castable as String. When you change more then one cell at once, Target.Value will return a array, wich is not castable to String.

So you must change each cell at a time:

```
Dim cell as Range, cells as Range
Set cells=Intersect(Target, Range("B9", "F10"))
If cells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
For each cell In cells.Cells
    Cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""
```

Comment: Will blow up if the cell content is empty

Comment: Not in my Excel 2010.

Comment: I have Excel 2010. Does an empty cell lie in the range being uppercased?

Comment: what do you mean? UCase expects a valid string expression. `Empty` is castable to empty string, so, no problem.

Comment: Good for you, it crashed on me for empty cells.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain my position. The original code is:

```
Target = UCase(Target)
```

which implies that you want to have Target range uppercase. The way to do it is by replacing this line with:

```
For Each c In Target
    If VarType(c.Value)=vbString Then
        c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
    End If
Next
```

which gives:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B9", "F10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        If VarType(c.Value)=vbString Then
            c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=""
```

Comment: See my original answer which explains why it is correct. Sorry for cheating LS_dev :-)

Comment: Agree! But @MattHead93 is not aware that Target may have multiple cells, and some out of B9:F10. Anyway, I would change `Not IsEmpty(c.Value)` to `VarType(c.Value)=vbString` to prevent casting non-string data to string and not crash with cell errors.

Comment: Well, I did not gain the ability to read people's mind. My response corrects Matt's code. If he faces another problem I think he should revise his question. I agree that your proposed check is safer and better.